# Android Gradle build failing with NoDescriptorForDeclarationException: Descriptor wasn't found for declaration SCRIPT

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

## Issue

I'm writing an app that'll work as a timesheet. I made multiple changes then compiled, and got this error. I cleaned the build and rebuilt and it worked.
This happened multiple times, but after a while it stopped working.

## Solutions tried

- Clean building the project
- Cleaning gradle cache manually
- Setting up build environment on linux server and building it there

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/nova/Desktop/private_key.pepk')
            storePassword 'REDACTED'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'REDACTED'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wittamit.timesheet"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.72"

}
```

## Error

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:extractDeepLinksDebug
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException: Descriptor wasn't found for declaration SCRIPT
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.findClassDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.getScriptDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitScript(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:204)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitScript(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtScript.accept(KtScript.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.resolveToDescriptor(ResolveSession.java:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:554)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:545)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

More details at [scans.gradle.com](https://scans.gradle.com/s/uiypk56o4tfnw)

Comment: Nicely formatted question! Just here to check if your question follows our guidelines, but i had to leave my kudos for the formatting of your question!

Comment: Thank you! I feel it's always better to ask a question that doesn't need expanding upon.